# jquery-ui sorting only single div present in another div,ignore all other divs inside it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

i have div structure like this :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="row1" class="row">
        <div class="c1"></div>
        <div class="c2"></div>
        <div class="c3"></div>
    </div>      
    <div id="row2" class="row">
        <div class="c1"></div>
        <div class="c2"></div>
        <div class="c3"></div>
    </div>      
    <div id="row3" class="row">
        <div class="c1"></div>
        <div class="c2"></div>
        <div class="c3"></div>
    </div>      

</div>
```

from the above code, what i want is , i should be able to sort only rows . means, exchanging row1 with row2 , like that .

What i tried :

```
 $("#container").sortable()
 $("#container").sortable({connectWith : '.row'})
 $(".row").sortable({connectWith : '#container'})
```

What is the solution , and i am facing this problem for every of my projects, can u explain how to exactly use that ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("#container").sortable();
```

is working just fine.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EvrLq/2/)**

Problem may cause by following:

- Forget to include jQuery
- Forget to inclue jQueryUI library
- don't wrap the script with `$(documet).ready(function() {...})`

Comment: previous answer working,$("#container >div"),  plz see worldtimebuddy.com once, there, we can  expand the vertical band,by clicking and dragging, what's going on there ? how can i implement that ?

Answer (score 0):

try simply

```
 $("#container").sortable({ handle : '.row'})
```

Comment: friends, all of your answers are right, but cant set everyone's as correct !

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/8zhhf/)?

If so, the only jQuery you need is:

```
 $("#container").sortable();
```

Comment: that problem solved, plz tell this one :  plz see worldtimebuddy.com once, there, we can  expand the vertical band,by clicking and dragging, what's going on there ? how can i implement that ?

Comment: @user1423849 That's a different question entirely, but all you need to do for that is make yourself a rectangle, position it absolute and the size you want, then hook into the `hover` method of each item you want the rectangle to move over, then inside the `hover` function set the rectangle's top and left properties to the current hovered elements top and left properties :)